# A way to create filter effects on an image or canvas server side>

Tags: node.js, canvas, imagemagick, skiacanvas

Is there a way to create (some what advanced) filter effects server side?

I've looked at [Skia Canvas](https://github.com/samizdatco/skia-canvas). Skia Canvas is close and supports all CSS filter effects except URL() which would allow me to use SVG filters.

I also found Image Magick but IIUC I don't know if I want to launch a separate process. I found a nodejs wrapper library [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemagick).

Basically, the end goal is to have a way to create or apply multiple possibly advanced filters in code. Something like:

```
var filters = [];
var dropShadow = new DropShadow(3,3,1, rgba(0,0,0,.5));
filters.push(dropShadow);
var blur = new Blur(3,6);
filters.push(blur);
var displacementMap = new DisplacementMap();
filters.push(displacementMap);

canvas.filters = filters;
```

I'm using nodejs